# How to set default arabic language using google translator in php

Tags: php, laravel, arabic, google-translate, arabic-support

I want open my website in Arabic language
function googleTranslateElementInit() {

```
                    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'ar', layout: 
                    google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 
                    'google_translate_element');
                }
```

I am using this function but its not working

Answer (score 1):

You can use this html and script:

```js
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'ar/ar'
  }, 'google_translate_element');
}

var flags = document.getElementsByClassName('flag_link');

function getData(lang, img) {

  var lang = lang;
  var languageSelect = document.querySelector("select.goog-te-combo");
  languageSelect.value = lang;
  languageSelect.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));

  $('#selectedImg').attr("src", img);
  localStorage.setItem('langFlag', img);
}

langFlag = localStorage.getItem('langFlag');
if (langFlag) {
  $('#selectedImg').attr("src", langFlag);
} else {
  $('#selectedImg').attr("src", 'https://nomadtvgroup.com/flag/flag-of-United-States-of-America.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div class="lag">
  <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <img class="img-fluid" id="selectedImg" src="https://kadlien.com/flag/flag-of-United-States-of-America.jpg" alt="" style="width:36px;">
                              </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a href="#" onclick="getData('en','https://kadlien.com/flag/flag-of-United-States-of-America.jpg')" class="dropdown-item flag_link eng" data-lang="en"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://kadlien.com/flag/flag-of-United-States-of-America.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a href="#" onclick="getData('ar','https://kadlien.com/flag/flag-of-Saudi-Arabia.jpg')" class="dropdown-item flag_link ar" data-lang="ar"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://kadlien.com/flag/flag-of-Saudi-Arabia.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a href="#" onclick="getData('hi','https://kadlien.com/flag/flag-of-India.jpg')" class="dropdown-item flag_link hi" data-lang="hi"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://kadlien.com/flag/flag-of-India.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a href="#" onclick="getData('de','https://kadlien.com/flag/flag-of-Germany.jpg')" class="dropdown-item flag_link de" data-lang="de"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://kadlien.com/flag/flag-of-Germany.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a href="#" onclick="getData('es','https://kadlien.com/flag/flag-of-Spain.jpg')" class="dropdown-item flag_link es" data-lang="es"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://kadlien.com/flag/flag-of-Spain.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <a href="#" onclick="getData('fr','https://kadlien.com/flag/french_southern_territories_texture.jpg')" class="dropdown-item flag_link fr" data-lang="fr"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://kadlien.com/flag/french_southern_territories_texture.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: your code throws some erros, please double-check.